# File Upload Curl Command to XMLHttpRequest Javascript?

Tags: javascript, curl, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I'm currently trying to create a file-upload page (w/ Electron) that uses the [GoFile API](https://gofile.io/api)

I'm a complete beginner with http requests, but have some prior Javascript/Electron experience.

How can I replicate this example CURL command inside of Javascript?

```
curl -F file=@file.txt https://srv-file6.gofile.io/uploadFile
```

In terminal this works perfectly with a specified file path, but when I pass a file path into an XMLHttp POST request inside of Javascript a "500" error is returned indicating that no file was uploaded.

Example:

```
      const Http2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

      const Post_url='https://'+server+'.gofile.io/uploadFile';

      Http2.open("POST", Post_url);

      Http2.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      Http2.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
          alert(Http2.responseText)
          
        }

      }
      let data = "file=@/Users/admin/Desktop/loading.gif"

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append(data);

      Http2.send(formData)
```

Comment: you have just to load the picture in memory before. If it's an upload input for example with the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) or fs.readFile() for NodeJS then you can attach this dataBlob to the formData `formData.append('file', blob, filename);`

Comment: I modified the code to append the blob, but now getting a 413 Payload Too Large error...